# How to ignore KeyErrors for multiple individual lines?

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

I'm looking up some data in a dictionary. But sometimes some pieces of the information aren't there and a `KeyError` is thrown. Is there a way I can say to ignore any errors that come up without surrounding each line with `try`/`except`?

I want something like:

```
ignore KeyError:
    a = data['foo']
    b = data['bar']
    c = data['fizz']
    d = data['buzz']
```

Instead of:

```
try:
    a = data['foo']
except KeyError:
    pass
try:
    b = data['bar']
except KeyError:
    pass
try:
    c = data['fizz']
except KeyError:
    pass
try:
    d = data['buzz']
except KeyError:
    pass
```

Comment: In general it's not a good idea, but in this specific case `.get` might be a good choice (you probably have to assign a value to `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` anyway).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.get()` , it returns `None` if the key does not exist. Example -

```
a = data.get('foo')
b = data.get('bar')
c = data.get('fizz')
d = data.get('buzz')
```

After this, if the `keys` like `'foo'` did not exist , `dict.get()` would return `None`. You can also specify, as a second argument, a default value to return in case the key does not exist. Example -

```
a = data.get('foo','<default value>') #the default value does not have to be a string, it can be anything.
```

This would return `'<default value>'` if the key does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use a for loop and a list of keys.

```
keys = ['foo', 'bar','fizz', 'buzz']
values = []

for k in keys:
     v = data.get(k)
     values.append(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can make use of .has_key:

```
a = None    
if data.has_key('foo'):
    a = data['foo']
print a
```

or
put the result of `data.keys()`
into a set() and check that first

Comment: Viable option except that the `key in data` is considered more Pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

It's only possible with `exec` (if you use `get()` method variables will be `None`):

```
code = """a = data["foo"]
b = data["bar"]
c = data["fizz"]
d = data["buzz"]"""
for line in code.splitlines():
    try:
        exec(line, globals())
    except Exception:
        pass
```

Answer (score -1):

Use on try block for all instead of single blocks because you have always the same except block.
e.g.

```
try:
  a = data['foo']
  b = data['bar']
  c = data['fizz']
  d = data['buzz']
except:
  pass
```

`

Comment: This won't work. If `'foo'` is not found, but others are present, they will not be retrieved.